# Concatenation in Haskell and confusion with AList ([a] -> [a])

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, concatenation, lambda-calculus

I have a project where we are improving the speed of concatenating a list in Haskell.
I'm new to Haskell and confused about  **AList ([a] -> [a])** Specifically how to convert my AppendedList to a regular List. Any help would be appreciated.

```
newtype AppendedList a = AList ([a] -> [a])

-- List[5] is represented as AList (\x -> 5:x) 
-- This function takes an argument and returns the AppendedList for that 
single :: a -> AppendedList a
single m = AList (\x -> m : x)


-- converts AppendedList to regular List
toList :: AppendedList a -> [a]
toList = ???
```

Comment: Take a look at *difference lists*.

Comment: It might help to try defining `empty :: AppendedList a` and `append :: a -> AppendedList a -> AppendedList a` so that `append 5 empty == single 5`.

Answer (score 6):

The toughest part is to not give you the answer directly :)

If you remember how lists are constructed in Haskell: `[1, 2, 3] = 1 : 2 : 3 : []`, with `[]` being the **empty list**.

Now let's "follow the types" (we also call this thought process TDD for Type Driven Development) and see what you have at hand:

```hs
toList :: AppendedList a -> [a]
toList (AList listFunction) = ???
```

and `listFunction` has the type `[a] -> [a]`. So you need to provide it a polymorphic list (i.e. a list of **any type**) so that it gives you back a list.

What is the only list of **any type** you know of? Pass this list to `listFunction` and everything will compile, which is a good indicator that it's probably right :D

I hope that helps without providing the plain answer (the goal is for you to learn!).

Answer (score 0):

`AppendedList a` is a type.

`AList f` is a datum of that type, with some function `f :: [a] -> [a]` "inside it".

`f` is a function from lists to lists with the same type of elements.

We can call it with `some_list :: [a]` to get `resulting_list :: [a]`:

```
f           :: [a] -> [a]
  some_list :: [a]
-------------------------
f some_list ::        [a]

resulting_list ::     [a]
resulting_list = f some_list
```

We can use `resulting_list` as `some_list`, too, i.e..

```
resulting_list = f resulting_list
```

because it has the same type, that fits `f`'s expectations (and because of Haskell's laziness). Thus

```
toList (...) = let { ... = ... } 
               in ...
```

is one possible definition. With it,

```
take 2 (toList (single 5))
```

would return `[5,5]`.

---

*edit:* Certainly `[5,5]` is not the list containing a *single* 5. Moreover, `take 4 ...` would return `[5,5,5,5]`, so our representation contains *any* amount of fives, not just one of them. But, it contains *only one* distinct number, 5.

This is reminiscent of *two* Applicative Functor instances for lists, the `[]` and the `ZipList`. `pure 5 :: [] Int` indeed contains just one five, but `pure 5 :: ZipList Int` contains any amount of fives, but *only* fives. Of course it's hard to append infinite lists, so it's mainly just a curiosity here. A food for thought.

In any case it shows that there's more than just one way to write a code that typechecks here. There's more than just one list at our disposal here. The simplest one is indeed `[]`, but the other one is .... our list itself!

Comment: I downvoted. While the hints here will lead to code that typechecks, and even runs and does something, the behavior it results in is almost certainly not what is intended. Difference lists are a really standard technique and almost certainly what the person who set this exercise is driving at (especially given the comment "`List[5] is represented as AList (\x -> 5:x)`"), not this.